# Chat layout behavior on iOS in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

I have a working chat layout but I'm just not very happy with it because it doesn't quite behave the way I want it to on iOS. I wanted to see how others handled it.

Here's my layout:

```xml
<Grid
   x:Name="ChatScreen"
   RowDefinitions="*,55"
   RowSpacing="3"
   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
   VerticalOptions="Fill">

   <!-- Messages Section -->
   <CollectionView
      x:Name="ConversationsCollection"
      Grid.Row="0"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"
      ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"
      VerticalOptions="Start">
      ... // Omitted for brevity
   </CollectionView>

   <!-- Entry Section -->
   <Grid
      Grid.Row="1"
      ColumnDefinitions="*,50"
      ColumnSpacing="5"
      HorizontalOptions="Fill"
      VerticalOptions="Start">

      <Editor
         Grid.Column="0"
         Text="{Binding Message}"
         AutoSize="TextChanges"
         Focused="ShiftGridUpward"
         Unfocused="ShiftGridDownward"
         HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

      <ImageButton
         Grid.Column="1"
         Command="{SendMessageCommand}"
         WidthRequest="45"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"
         VerticalOptions="Center">
         <ImageButton.Source>
            ... Omitted for brevity
         </ImageButton.Source>
      </ImageButton>

   </Grid>

</Grid>
```

And in code behind, I handle shifting the `Grid` up or down like this:

```cs
private void ShiftGridUpward(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        ChatScreen.TranslateTo(0, -150, 100);
}

private void ShiftGridDownward(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
        ChatScreen.TranslateTo(0, 0, 100);
}
```

Here are the problems I'm having with this layout which are more quality than function issues because this layout works OK but quality doesn't seem great on iOS.

First issue is with shifting the `Grid` up and down so that the soft keyboard doesn't cover the `Editor`. Below I provided a link to a video that shows the behavior. As you can see, initially, the shift isn't enough and the soft keyboard still covers the `Editor`. In subsequent tries, it works better, though I still don't find the behavior nice and smooth.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/iQuest/chat_screen_issue.MP4

The second issue is with making sure the last message is displayed, on load as well as after sending/receiving a message.

As you can see in the video, on iOS, the last message is not really showing properly. It's behind the `Editor`. The `ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepLastItemInView"` seems to have no effect whatsoever on iOS. So, I handle it by getting the index number of the last message and then manually calling the function below. Even though I call this function on inital load, as you can see, the last message is still not properly positioned.

```cs
private void ScrollToLastMessage(object sender, int index)
{
    ConversationsCollection.ScrollTo(index, position: ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, animate: true);
}
```

I'd appreciate it if those who've implemented a chat screen successfully in a .NET MAUI app could give me some pointers here.

P.S. BTW, everything works nicely on Android. These are all iOS issues here.

Comment: It's worth nothing that like a hundred other "cross platform solutions", unfortunately "cross platform solutions" don't work.  If there are small layout issues, I'd suggest just leave it and move on.

Comment: I think the issue with what you are doing right now is that you are using ScrollPosition MakeVisible and that's what it's doing, maybe trying using the other available options on iOS and see if that fixes anything